Failed to read key fin from store
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolExcept

storePassword=finpro
keyPassword=finpro
keyAlias=fin
storeFile=/Users/macbookpro/Ongoing works/Finpro/fin_pro/keystore/fin-pro.jks

signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }


I don't know what exactly did you do to mess it up, but here's what works for me always across projects

Create a secrets.properties file at the root level
Add the following keys and values as per requirement(Ensure no whitespaces)

DEBUG_KEY_ALIAS=
DEBUG_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=
DEBUG_KEY_PASSWORD=
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=
RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=


Load them in your app level build.gradle.kts file as follows

// Load property file
val properties = Properties()
val propertyFile = File(rootDir, "secrets.properties")
InputStreamReader(FileInputStream(propertyFile), Charsets.UTF_8).use { reader -> properties.load(reader)
}

android {

signingConfigs {
  create("my_release_config"){
     storeFile = file("keystore/release.keystore") // Should be in the root folder
     keyAlias = properties.getProperty("RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS", "default")
     keyPassword = properties.getProperty("RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD", "default")
     storePassword = properties.getProperty("RELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD", "default")
  }
}

}



Use the keytool command to list the aliases in the keystore and verify that the alias "fin" exists. Ensure that the alias "fin" is present in the output.
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/macbookpro/Ongoing works/Finpro/fin_pro/keystore/fin-pro.jks

after that, sync your project with Gradle files and perform a clean build:
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease

